# Function with lock.aquire() called when its condition is no longer met

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I found *a* solution to this little issue, however I'm still wondering why it occurred in the first place.

In my code, I (think I) have a main thread as well as another thread.

From the function dealing with the main thread, if the received input is "", then a function (function_a) that acquires a/the lock is called.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import threading

class Some_Class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def function_a(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        print("function_A called")
        self.lock.release()

    def function_b(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        print("function_B called")
        self.lock.release()

some_class = Some_Class()

def main_thread():
    while True:
        if input() == "":
            some_class.function_a()
        time.sleep(0.5) # <-----

def thread():
    while True:
        some_class.function_b()
        time.sleep(0.5)

def main():
    threading.Thread(target=thread).start()
    main_thread()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So the issue goes away when i remove the time.sleep(0.5) in the main_thread() function. However, I still don't understand why when there is the time.sleep(0.5) in the main_thread() function, function_a is called for a while after the user holds the enter key for a few seconds.

Could someone explain the reason(s) for this phenomenon?

Thanks.

Edit: If I was being unclear regarding my question:

- When there's no time.sleep() in the the main_function(), function_a stops printing as soon as enter is no longer pressed. But when time.sleep() is there, function_a continues to print for a while.
  I was wondering why it does that...

Comment: Can you explain what exactly happens and what you think is supposed to happen?

Comment: Cannot understand what you mean? As `print` is an atomic operation, your `lock` is totally meaningless. All phenomenon you see may be just lucky.

Comment: I made an edit at the end of my question if that helps...

Comment: This has nothing to do with locks or threads; it’s just your terminal’s input buffer.  Did you expect it to discard your input just because the program is slow to read it?

Comment: 1 yr later, I understand; I was just naive about how writing to terminal works. Thanks.